# Pig Latin Converter Issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, slice, indexof

Im working on a function that converts a normal word to pig latin, and I can't get everything to come together; it has to work for california, gloves, and eight. What isn't working right?

```
    function translate(word) {
      var result = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(word[-1]) === -1) {
            // probably failing around here 
          result = word.slice(i);
          result += word.slice(0, i);
          break;
        }
      }
      if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(word[0]) !== -1) {
        result = word + "way";
      } else {
        result += "ay";
      }

      return result;
    }
```

Comment: pretend the word[-1] is word[i]

Comment: what input gives you wrong answer?

Comment: describe what is the input you send, what is the output and what you expected?

Comment: california -> californiaay

Comment: aliforniacay, oveglay, and eightway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your working function, When asking this type of questions for a solution describe clearly what you tried so far in you question and what you looking for.

```
function translateW(word) {
      var result = "", e="";

      if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(word[0]) !== -1) {
        return word + "way";
      }


      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(word[i])!== -1) {

          e = word.slice(0, i); 
          result = word.slice(i); 
          result += e; 
          break;
        }
      }      

      return result += "ay";
    }
```